# How to program Xilinx 7 series FPGA through an SD card?

Tags: boot, xilinx

I know that Xilinx Zynq board can be programmed easily through an SD card wherein it writes the programmable bit file to the SPI flash.

Is there a similar option for 7 series Xilinx devices especially Artix 7 devices to be programmed through an SD card.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you can't. Further answers are located at [Xilinx forums](https://forums.xilinx.com/t5/Xilinx-Boards-and-Kits/How-to-program-AC701-FPGA-through-an-SD-card/td-p/738244).